# Creating standalone application with same directories and qgis-auth.db

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, standalone

I try to have a standalone `QgsApplication` ([api documentation](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/core/QgsApplication.html)), but, instead of a lot of code samples found like this one below (I'm on Ubuntu):

```
from qgis.core import QgsApplication

QgsApplication.setPrefixPath("/usr", True)
app = QgsApplication([], False)
app.initQgis()
```

I want the same result for `print(app.showSettings())` as in the QGIS Desktop application.

In QGIS Desktop :

```py
>>> print(QgsApplication.instance().showSettings())

État de l'application
variable d'environnement QGIS_PREFIX_PATH :     
Préfixe:        /usr
Chemin des extensions:      /usr/lib/qgis/plugins
Chemin des paquets de données:  /usr/share/qgis
Nom du thème actif: default
Chemin du thème actif:  /usr/share/qgis/resources/themes/default/icons/
Chemin du thème par défaut: :/images/themes/default/
Chemins de recherche SVG:   /usr/share/qgis/svg/
        /home/me/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/svg/
Chemin de la BD utilisateur:    /usr/share/qgis/resources/qgis.db
Chemin de la BD d'authentification: /home/me/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/qgis-auth.db
```

In standalone Python script :

```py
>>> from qgis.core import QgsApplication

>>> QgsApplication.setPrefixPath("/usr", True)
>>> QgsApplication.setThemeName("default")
>>> QgsApplication.setAuthDatabaseDirPath("/home/me/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/qgis-auth.db")
>>> app = QgsApplication([], False)
>>> app.initQgis()
>>> print(app.showSettings())

Application state:
QGIS_PREFIX_PATH env var:       
Prefix:     /usr
Plugin Path:        /usr/lib/qgis/plugins
Package Data Path:  /usr/share/qgis
Active Theme Name:  default
Active Theme Path:  /usr/share/qgis/resources/themes/default/icons/
Default Theme Path: :/images/themes/default/
SVG Search Paths:   /usr/share/qgis/svg/
        /home/me/.local/share/profiles/default/svg/
User DB Path:   /usr/share/qgis/resources/qgis.db
Auth DB Path:   /home/me/.local/share/profiles/default/qgis-auth.db
```

It creates a new `profiles` directory and it's not what I want.

I also tried to [initialize the db auth Manager](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/authentication.html#init-the-manager-and-set-the-master-password) with no results, it leads to a Python segmentation fault.

How to have the same `Auth DB Path` in QGIS Desktop and in a standalone Python script?

In summary, how to have (done, see the edit) :

<strike>`Auth DB Path:  /home/me/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/qgis-auth.db`</strike>

Working on Ubuntu 18.04, QGIS 3.8.

---

With the proposition of @GermánCarrillo:

- call `QgsApplication.setAuthDatabaseDirPath("/home/me/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/")` (without `qgis-auth.db`) after `app.initQgis()`

it works but it failed after :

```py
>>> from qgis.core import QgsApplication

>>> QgsApplication.setPrefixPath("/usr", True)
>>> QgsApplication.setThemeName("default")
>>> app = QgsApplication([], False)
>>> app.initQgis()
>>> QgsApplication.setAuthDatabaseDirPath("/home/me/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/")
>>> print(app.showSettings())

[... same as before ...]
Auth DB Path:   /home/me/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/qgis-auth.db
```

Ok, I have the correct `Auth DB Path` but if I try to get the QGIS app `authManager`, the database path is still not correct :

```
>>> authMgr = app.authManager()
>>> authMgr.authenticationDatabasePath()

'/home/me/.local/share/profiles/default/qgis-auth.db'
```

I thought in the first place that if the `Auth DB Path` of the QGIS app is properly configured, the database path of the app `authManager` would be too.

Now, how to have :

- `app.authManager().authenticationDatabasePath()` equals to `/home/me/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/qgis-auth.db`

or how to get access to the Desktop app credentials / authentication database ?

Comment: I think you need to pass the folder path (`"/home/me/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/"`) and not the file path (`"/home/me/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/qgis-auth.db"`) to `QgsApplication.setAuthDatabaseDirPath()`. Like this: `QgsApplication.setAuthDatabaseDirPath("/home/me/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/")`. Additionally, only call the method `QgsApplication.setAuthDatabaseDirPath(...)` after calling `app.initQgis()`.

Comment: @GermánCarrillo : it works perfectly, exactly with what you said. The new `profiles` directory is still created but the `Auth DB Path` is correct. But, `app.authManager().authenticationDatabasePath()` still not correct ...

Comment: I didn't publish it as an answer because it seems it didn't work flawlessly.

Comment: Many thanks for the comments and the help, I've create an issue for the QGIS project : https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/32353.

Comment: @GermánCarrillo : check the working answer !

Comment: Good job! Glad that you found it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the [C++ API of QgsApplication](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsApplication.html#a79c51bd32dbdb7c81b86c8c28040d991), the class instantiation is described as :

```cpp
QgsApplication::QgsApplication  (   int &   argc,
        char **     argv,
        bool    GUIenabled,
        const QString &     profileFolder = QString(),
        const QString &     platformName = "desktop" 
    )
```

When looking in the `QgsApplication.initQgis` code, the `profileFolder` (as `sProfilePath` variable) is used.

So, I tried to instantiate my Python `QgsApplication` class as for C++ and it works.

Here the pyQGIS code :

```
from qgis.core import QgsApplication

QgsApplication.setPrefixPath("/usr", True)
QgsApplication.setThemeName("default")
app = QgsApplication([], False, "/home/me/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default")
app.initQgis()
authMgr = app.authManager()

print(authMgr.authenticationDatabasePath())
```

returns :

```py
'/home/me/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/qgis-auth.db'
```